# Trying to build Flutter app for distribution. Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to build an `apk` to upload to Firebase App Distribution.

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease appDistributionUploadRelease` I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
>
>   > Missing app id. Please check that it was passed in and try again

The app ID is specified in `[my project]/android/app/build.gradle`.

How can I fix this error?

edit: I found that I can just upload the `apk` file manually to `Firebase App Distribution` but the warning said that I would need to fix the problem before I could use `Codemagic`.

Answer (score 0):

I was found the same problem, I found that just add appId

```
 firebaseAppDistribution {
     appId="your app id"
     releaseNotes="Release notes for full version"
     testers="full@testers.com"
 }
```

> Read the document
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle#step_3_configure_your_distribution_properties
>
> [image]